# 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', when fired inside of the 'wp_update_nav_menu' hook, returns old menu items, instead of new

Tags: menus

So, I need to run wp_get_nav_menu_items function once the menu is updated, to get the newest menu item list.

My code currently looks like this:

```
function get_menu_items( $menuId, $menuData = null ) {
    if($menuData) {
        // Lets assume that I have 4 menu items and I remove 1
        // This should return 3 menu items, but it returns 4 still
        $menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menuData['menu-name'] );

        wp_die( var_dump( $menuItems ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'get_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

As stated inside of the WordPress Code Reference on this link
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_update_nav_menu/
this hook runs after the navigation menu is successfully updated.

Now I have actually read through source code and figured out that this hook is called inside of the wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 381. 
My guess why this doesn't work correctly is because the Database is still being updated at the point of the hook call.

I have tried and added my custom hook (temporarily) to the wp-admin/nav-menus.php, after line 375 like this:

```
do_action( 'finished_updating_menu', $nav_menu_selected_title );
```

This seems to solve the problem, but modifying the WordPress Core is not the good practice and I consider it temporary solution. Does anybody else knows the other way I can achieve this?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question

Comment: The problem its this hook run after the navigation menu is updated but before the menu items is updated.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. Do you perhaps know of any solutions or workarounds to this problem that don't include modifying WordPress Core? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can get most of the data from the `$_POST`